# Is there any possibilities to get fired 'onload' event from 'iframe' in a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If there any possible way to fire onload event of iframe ?, Because for my requirement I need to load external websites in iframe. Even though some of the sites not allowing to load their pages in iframe

Eg: https://www.google.co.in, I need to validate the url whether that's valid to load in iframe or not. could any one suggest me to resolve?

Comment: i just created and assigned url dynamically based on user input . and selected this iframe from javascript and registered onload event using the bellow answer 0 but thats not triggering when page loaded successfully My code is here

Comment: var iframe=document.getElementById("ifrm");
 if (iframe.attachEvent){
   iframe.attachEvent("onload", function(){
   console.log("success",iframe);
           
       });
  } else {
      iframe.onload = function(){
   console.log("success",iframe);
           alert("Local iframe is now loaded.");
   /*if(iframe.contentDocument) { 
        console.log(iframe.contentWindow); 
   } else {
        console.log(iframe.contentWindow); 
   }*/
      };
 }

Comment: But i need to confirm whether the page loaded successfully or not so that i can make the user to aware about the failure or success. Can any one suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
if (iframe.attachEvent){
     iframe.attachEvent("onload", function(){
         alert("Local iframe is now loaded."(www.111cn.net));
     });
 } else {
     iframe.onload = function(){
         alert("Local iframe is now loaded.");
     };
 }
```

Comment: You said *try*, can you verify why this could solve the problem or are you just guessing? Please try to only answer when you have good reason to think your answer will solve the issue.

Comment: But its not solving my goal, the onload event triggers always not when page loaded successfully. I need to know whether the page is loaded successfully or not, so thought of onload.